# Python faster than D?? IO operations seem to slow D down a lot... what's going on?

Tags: python, d

I wrote a virtual machine language to assembly translator for a computer systems course I'm taking (using the nand2tetris curriculum). I originally wrote it in Python, but since I'm learning D, I thought I'd translate it. D is fairly close to Python syntactically, so it wasn't too difficult. I assumed that D, being a performance language and compiled, would be at least as fast as Python and on a large file, would be much faster. But the opposite is true! Despite identical algorithms, D consistently performed slightly slower than python when I constructed a very large file to compile. On a file approximately 500000 lines long, python consistently took about 2.6 seconds to complete, while D consistently took about 3. This isn't an enormous gap, but it's notable that python would be at all faster.

I don't want to suggest that I'm naive enough to think that python is actually faster than D overall; however, in this instance it seems at the very least that D is not intuitively faster. I'd appreciate some input on possible sources of performance decreases in my D code. I think the bottleneck might be on IO operations, but I'm not sure.

The source code is below. The details aren't that important; some assembly language templates are allocated and then there's a linear pass through the virtual machine language, translating each instruction to an equivalent block of assembly code.

**EDIT:** after recompiling the D code using `dmd -O -release -inline -m64`, D comes out the victor with a time of 2.20s on the input. However, the question still remains of why with almost identical code, D seems to perform slower than python.

**EDIT 2:** using the advice from below, I switched from using a simple list of strings, to using an `appender!string()`, and improved the time by a noticeable amount. It's worth mentioning however, that if you have a bunch of strings in an `appender`, **do not** write them to a file with a command like:

```
auto outputfile = File("foo.txt","w");
foreach(str; my_appender.data)
   outputfile.write(str);
```

Rather instead, write something like:

```
auto outputfile = File("foo.txt","w");
outputfile.write(my_appender.data);
```

The second example will give you a small performance increase over using a simple `string[]`. But using the first one gave me a huge performance hit, doubling the execution time.

Changing to an `appender!string()`, the compilation of the aforementioned large file took about 2.75 seconds (to Python's 2.8), where the original had taken about 3. Doing this, and also using the optimization flags in `dmd`, gave a total compilation time of `1.98` seconds! :)

Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

operations_dict = {"add":"+", "sub":"-",
                   "and":"&", "or":"|",
                   "not":"!", "neg":"-",
                   "lt":"JLT", "gt":"JGT",
                   "eq":"JEQ", "leq":"JLE",
                   "geq":"JGE"}

vars_dict = {"this":("THIS","M"),
             "that":("THAT","M"),
             "argument":("ARG","M",),
             "local":("LCL","M",),
             "static":("f.%d","M",),
             "temp":("TEMP","A",)}

start = "@SP\nAM=M-1\n"
end = "@SP\nM=M+1\n"

binary_template = start + "D=M\n\
@SP\n\
AM=M-1\n\
M=M%sD\n" + end

unary_template = start + "M=%sM\n" + end

comp_template = start + "D=M\n\
@SP\n\
AM=M-1\n\
D=M-D\n\
@COMP.%d.TRUE\n\
D;%s\n\
@COMP.%d.FALSE\n\
0;JMP\n\
(COMP.%d.TRUE)\n\
@SP\n\
A=M\n\
M=-1\n\
@SP\n\
M=M+1\n\
@COMP.%d.END\n\
0;JMP\n\
(COMP.%d.FALSE)\n\
@SP\n\
A=M\n\
M=0\n" + end + "(COMP.%d.END)\n"

push_tail_template = "@SP\n\
A=M\n\
M=D\n\
@SP\n\
M=M+1\n"

push_const_template = "@%d\nD=A\n" + push_tail_template

push_var_template = "@%d\n\
D=A\n\
@%s\n\
A=%s+D\n\
D=M\n" + push_tail_template

push_staticpointer_template = "@%s\nD=M\n" + push_tail_template

pop_template = "@%d\n\
D=A\n\
@%s\n\
D=%s+D\n\
@R13\n\
M=D\n\
@SP\n\
AM=M-1\n\
D=M\n\
@R13\n\
A=M\n\
M=D\n"

pop_staticpointer_template = "@SP\n\
AM=M-1\n\
D=M\n\
@%s\n\
M=D"


type_dict = {"add":"arithmetic", "sub":"arithmetic",
                   "and":"arithmetic", "or":"arithmetic",
                   "not":"arithmetic", "neg":"arithmetic",
                   "lt":"arithmetic", "gt":"arithmetic",
                   "eq":"arithmetic", "leq":"arithmetic",
                   "geq":"arithmetic", 
                   "push":"memory", "pop":"memory"}

binary_ops = ["add", "sub", "and", "or"]
unary_ops = ["not", "neg"]
comp_ops = ["lt", "gt", "eq", "leq", "geq"]


op_count = 0
line_count = 0
output = ["// Assembly file generated by my awesome VM compiler\n"]

def compile_operation(op):
    global line_count

    if (op[0:2] == "//") or (len(op.split()) == 0):
        return ""

    # print "input: " + op
    operation = op.split()[0]
    header = "// '" + op +  "' (line " + str(line_count) + ")\n"
    line_count += 1

    if type_dict[operation] == "arithmetic":
        return header + compile_arithmetic(op)
    elif type_dict[operation] == "memory":
        return header + compile_memory(op)

def compile_arithmetic(op):
    global op_count
    out_string = ""
    if op in comp_ops:
        out_string += comp_template % (op_count, operations_dict[op], op_count, \
            op_count, op_count, op_count, op_count)
        op_count += 1
    elif op in unary_ops:
        out_string += unary_template % operations_dict[op]
    else:
        out_string += binary_template % operations_dict[op]
    return out_string

def compile_memory(op):
    global output
    instructions = op.split()
    inst = instructions[0]
    argtype = instructions[1]
    val = int(instructions[2])
    if inst == "push":
        if argtype == "constant":
            return push_const_template % val
        elif argtype == "static":
            return push_staticpointer_template % ("f." + str(val))
        elif argtype == "pointer":
            if val == 0:
                return push_staticpointer_template % ("THIS")
            else:
                return push_staticpointer_template % ("THAT")
        else:
            return push_var_template % (val, vars_dict[argtype][0], vars_dict[argtype][1])
    elif inst == "pop":
        if argtype != "constant":
            if argtype == "static":
                return pop_staticpointer_template % ("f." + str(val))
            elif argtype == "pointer":
                if val == 0:
                    return pop_staticpointer_template % "THIS"
                else:
                    return pop_staticpointer_template % "THAT"
            else:
                return pop_template % (val, vars_dict[argtype][0], vars_dict[argtype][1])

def main():
    global output

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        inputfname = "test.txt"
    else:
        inputfname = sys.argv[1]
    outputfname = inputfname.split('.')[0] + ".asm"

    inputf = open(inputfname)
    output += ["// Input filename: %s\n" % inputfname]
    for line in inputf.readlines():
        output += [compile_operation(line.strip())]

    outputf = open(outputfname, 'w')
    for outl in output:
        outputf.write(outl)

    outputf.write("(END)\n@END\n0;JMP");
    inputf.close()
    outputf.close()
    print "Output written to " + outputfname


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

D:

```
import std.stdio, std.string, std.conv, std.format, std.c.stdlib;

string[string] operations_dict, type_dict;
string[][string] vars_dict;
string[] arithmetic, memory, comp_ops, unary_ops, binary_ops, lines, output;
string start, end, binary_template, unary_template,
        comp_template, push_tail_template, push_const_template,
        push_var_template, push_staticpointer_template,
        pop_template, pop_staticpointer_template;
int op_count, line_count;

void build_dictionaries() {
    vars_dict = ["this":["THIS","M"],
                 "that":["THAT","M"],
                 "argument":["ARG","M"],
                 "local":["LCL","M"],
                 "static":["f.%d","M"],
                 "temp":["TEMP","A"]];

    operations_dict = ["add":"+", "sub":"-",
                   "and":"&", "or":"|",
                   "not":"!", "neg":"-",
                   "lt":"JLT", "gt":"JGT",
                   "eq":"JEQ", "leq":"JLE",
                   "geq":"JGE"];

    type_dict = ["add":"arithmetic", "sub":"arithmetic",
                   "and":"arithmetic", "or":"arithmetic",
                   "not":"arithmetic", "neg":"arithmetic",
                   "lt":"arithmetic", "gt":"arithmetic",
                   "eq":"arithmetic", "leq":"arithmetic",
                   "geq":"arithmetic", 
                   "push":"memory", "pop":"memory"];

    binary_ops = ["add", "sub", "and", "or"];
    unary_ops = ["not", "neg"];
    comp_ops = ["lt", "gt", "eq", "leq", "geq"];
}

bool is_in(string s, string[] list) {
    foreach (str; list)
        if (str==s) return true;
    return false;
}

void build_strings() {
    start = "@SP\nAM=M-1\n";
    end = "@SP\nM=M+1\n";

    binary_template = start ~ "D=M\n"
    "@SP\n"
    "AM=M-1\n"
    "M=M%sD\n" ~ end;

    unary_template = start ~ "M=%sM\n" ~ end;

    comp_template = start ~ "D=M\n"
    "@SP\n"
    "AM=M-1\n"
    "D=M-D\n"
    "@COMP.%s.TRUE\n"
    "D;%s\n"
    "@COMP.%s.FALSE\n"
    "0;JMP\n"
    "(COMP.%s.TRUE)\n"
    "@SP\n"
    "A=M\n"
    "M=-1\n"
    "@SP\n"
    "M=M+1\n"
    "@COMP.%s.END\n"
    "0;JMP\n"
    "(COMP.%s.FALSE)\n"
    "@SP\n"
    "A=M\n"
    "M=0\n" ~ end ~ "(COMP.%s.END)\n";

    push_tail_template = "@SP\n"
    "A=M\n"
    "M=D\n"
    "@SP\n"
    "M=M+1\n";

    push_const_template = "@%s\nD=A\n" ~ push_tail_template;

    push_var_template = "@%s\n"
    "D=A\n"
    "@%s\n"
    "A=%s+D\n"
    "D=M\n" ~ push_tail_template;

    push_staticpointer_template = "@%s\nD=M\n" ~ push_tail_template;

    pop_template = "@%s\n"
    "D=A\n"
    "@%s\n"
    "D=%s+D\n"
    "@R13\n"
    "M=D\n"
    "@SP\n"
    "AM=M-1\n"
    "D=M\n"
    "@R13\n"
    "A=M\n"
    "M=D\n";

    pop_staticpointer_template = "@SP\n"
    "AM=M-1\n"
    "D=M\n"
    "@%s\n"
    "M=D";
}

void init() {
    op_count = 0;
    line_count = 0;
    output = ["// Assembly file generated by my awesome VM compiler\n"];
    build_strings();
    build_dictionaries();
}

string compile_operation(string op) {
    if (op.length == 0 || op[0..2] == "//")
        return "";
    string operation = op.split()[0];
    string header = "// '" ~ op ~  "' (line " ~ to!string(line_count) ~ ")\n";
    ++line_count;

    if (type_dict[operation] == "arithmetic")
        return header ~ compile_arithmetic(op);
    else
        return header ~ compile_memory(op);
}

string compile_arithmetic(string op) {
    if (is_in(op, comp_ops)) {
        string out_string = format(comp_template, op_count, operations_dict[op], op_count, 
            op_count, op_count, op_count, op_count);
        op_count += 1;
        return out_string;
    } else if (is_in(op, unary_ops))
        return format(unary_template, operations_dict[op]);
    else
        return format(binary_template, operations_dict[op]);
}

string compile_memory(string op) {
    string[] instructions = op.split();
    string inst = instructions[0];
    string argtype = instructions[1];
    int val = to!int(instructions[2]);
    if (inst == "push") {
        if (argtype == "constant") {
            return format(push_const_template, val);
        } else if (argtype == "static")
            return format(push_staticpointer_template, ("f." ~ to!string(val)));
        else if (argtype == "pointer")
            if (val == 0)
                return format(push_staticpointer_template, "THIS");
            else
                return format(push_staticpointer_template, "THAT");
        else
            return format(push_var_template, val, vars_dict[argtype][0], vars_dict[argtype][1]);
    } else {
        if (argtype != "constant") {
            if (argtype == "static")
                return format(pop_staticpointer_template, ("f." ~ to!string(val)));
            else if (argtype == "pointer") {
                if (val == 0)
                    return format(pop_staticpointer_template, "THIS");
                else
                    return format(pop_staticpointer_template, "THAT");
            }
            else
                return format(pop_template, val, vars_dict[argtype][0], vars_dict[argtype][1]);
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
}

void main(string args[]) {
    init();
    if (args.length < 2) {
        writefln("usage: %s <filename>", args[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    string inputfname = args[1];
    string outputfname = args[1].split(".")[0] ~ ".asm";

    auto inputf = File(inputfname, "r");
    output ~= format("// Input filename: %s\n", inputfname);
    foreach (line; inputf.byLine) {
        output ~= compile_operation(to!string(line).strip);
    }
    inputf.close();

    auto outputf = File(outputfname, "w");
    foreach (outl; output)
        outputf.write(outl);

    outputf.write("(END)\n@END\n0;JMP");
    outputf.close();
    writeln("Compilation successful. Output written to " ~ outputfname);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling to see what is happening?
Don't assume. Use the `-profile` compiler flag.

Comment: You might also want to add `-noboundscheck` when compiling the D code. I'm not sure it would cause any difference in this case, but generally, you might want that in a release version. It would also be interesting to see gdc's or ldc's performance.

Comment: @Daniel can you explain what -profile does? I ran `dmd -profile vmt.d` (vmt.d is the name of my file) and when I ran the program on a large input file, it just hung (or I didn't wait long enough, but either way).

Comment: Try compiling with GDC for optimal performance.

Comment: @yaz `-noboundscheck` seems to shave a few tenths of a second off the running time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `output` variable use `Appender` ([docs](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_array.html#.Appender)):

```
import std.array : appender;

void main() {
   auto output = appender!string("// Assembly file generated by my awesome VM compiler\n");
   //...
   output.put(format("// Input filename: %s\n", inputfname));
   foreach (line; inputf.byLine) {
       output.put(compile_operation(line.to!string().strip()));
   }
   //...
   outputf.write(output.data());
   //...
}
```

Also, I suggest that you should change your `type_dict` to something like `int[string]` and use it with integer constants.

```
int[string] type_dict;

const TYPE_ARITHMETIC = 0,
    TYPE_MEMORY = 1;

//...
type_dict = ["add": TYPE_ARITHMETIC, "push": TYPE_MEMORY]; // etc
//...

//...
if (type_dict[operation] == TYPE_ARITHMETIC) {
    //...
}
//...
```

Use `canFind` method ([docs](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm.html#canFind)) instead of custom `is_in`. Or even try `SortedRange` ([docs](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#.SortedRange)).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using `std.array.appender` for output instead of array concatenation in your main function as `appender` minimizes the number of allocations and is generally optimized for appending. You can also experiment with `reserve`.

```
//Note: untested code
import std.array;
auto output = appender!string();

void init() {
   ...
   output.put("// Assembly file generated by my awesome VM compiler\n");
   ...
}

void main() {
   ...
   output.put(format("// Input filename: %s\n", inputfname));
   foreach (line; inputf.byLine) {
       output.put(compile_operation(to!string(line).strip));
   }
   ...
   foreach (outl; output.data)
       outputf.write(outl);
   ...
}
```

Comment: I put it in, but oddly enough, that doubled (!) the running time of the program. Wow, what is going on there. By the way, apparently it's illegal to declare `auto output = appender!string();` in a global scope. I tried to declare it just as `auto output;` and initialize it in my `init()` function, but it didn't like the ambiguous type. Since I'm not sure what type it is (one of my few gripes with D are these seemingly anonymous types), and declaring it as an Appender didn't work either, I changed `init` to return `auto` and declared `output` in `init`. Any smoother way to do this?

Comment: string is an alias for `(immutable char)[]` and appender needs to change the elements of the array, changing it to `appender!char` will solve that. and there is a template somewhere in the lib to properly change the result to string with `assumeUnique` (assuming the array is only referenced locally)

Comment: "and appender needs to change the elements of the array" - What?